# Which of the following is correct?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I've been asked to correct this sentence:

> Have you ever felt discouraged by many corrections on (insert website name)?

For context, this is in relation to a website where you post your writing and get it corrected by experts in that field.

I'm considering three options:

1. Have you ever gotten discouraged when you've received many corrections?
2. Have you ever gotten discouraged when you receive many corrections?
3. Have you ever gotten discouraged when you received many corrections?

I'm sure the first option is the answer, but my brain is not working right now, so if someone could please kindly confirm.

Also, would it make a difference if I changed *gotten* to *felt*?

Comment: "Have you ever felt discouraged for receiving so many corrections?"

Comment: To be clear, I mean 'after receiving a lot of corrections'. Does it still fit?

Comment: yeah, I was just about to add to Othya's route --    "Have you ever felt discouraged after receiving many corrections on <website>?"

Comment: Cersei, what is urgent to you may not be urgent for us.  Do not mark you questions "urgent".  I promise you won't get answers any faster, and you risk putting off people who might have otherwise helped you. I've also edited your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

So the original sentence is technically correct:

> Have you ever felt discouraged by many corrections on (insert website
>   name)?

None of your three answers are correct, as they all use the slang "have gotten". I might change the original to something like:

> Have you ever felt discouraged after receiving several corrections on the website?

Finally, to answer your last question, yes, changing "gotten" to "felt" would help.

Comment: Whoa, I did not know that 'have gotten' was slang! I've been using it everywhere. 
Thank you for your answer , it was very helpful!